# CSS styled columns moving vertical position depending on number of sub elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

For a new application I want to create a row of columns (styled with bootstrap3) that scroll vertically and are drop targets (using jquery-ui).

I'm fairly successful in my attempts to style this but the columns all shift up or down depending on the number of droppables I place in them.

The general structure of my page is as follows:

```
<div class="pipeline">
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-fase">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Fase 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body fase-deals">
            <div class="deal">
                <h4 class="deal-title">My Deal #1</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="deal">
                <h4 class="deal-title">My Deal #2</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="deal">
                <h4 class="deal-title">My Deal #3</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="deal">
                <h4 class="deal-title">My Deal #4</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-fase">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Fase 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body fase-deals">
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

Styling this using CSS works, I can add any number of columns and scroll horizontally. However each column (bootstrap panel in my code) has a vertical position depending on the number of items (div.deal in my code). 
So when adding an item using drag and drop the columns moves upwards, removing an item moves my column downwards.

I have my source in this jsfiddle that demonstrates my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/31qxxs6r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to your cards like this:

```
.panel-fase {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and there you go! Please let me know your feedback. Thanks!

check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ang7gt2g/)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much! Would you mind elaborating on the thought behind this? I don't see any real logic and would like to learn more so I can prevent stupid questions like this ;-)

Comment: happens because of `inline-block` display... you can read more into it I guess :)